# Deshabilitar un en enlace según fecha y hora

Tags: javascript

Hola gente le estuve dando vueltas a esto y no puedo encontrar la solución,
La idea es para que un enlace que tiene un link tiene que estar habilitado en un horario especifico y y deshabilitado por ejemplo los domingos.
es la mi primera vez que uso lenguaje y mi primer pregunta gracias por la ayuda!

javascript: horarios.js

```
 var time = new Date();
 var hora = time.getHours();
 document.write(hora);
 if(hora >= 20 && hora < 8) {
 enlace.href="#";
 }
```

html:

```
 <body>
 <script src="horarios.js"></script>
 <a id="enlace" href="formulario_de_contactos.html" >este enlace</a>
</body>   `
```

Comment: Checa por favor [ask], edita y agrega tu código

Comment: Hola Enzo, las preguntas pidiendo ayuda con problemas o depuración deben incluir una descripción de lo que se quiere hacer, el código intentado, y los mensajes de error o dificultades encontradas. Tal y como está redactada esta pregunta, es muy amplia. Por favor, añade más datos (y a ser posible, código). Lee [ask] y visita el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Asumamos que quieres que el enlace esté deshabilitado entre las 8 de la tarde y las 8 de la mañana, por lo que veo en el ejemplo. (por favor, para futuras ocasiones, intenta indentar para hacer más fácil la lectura).

Lo que parece que te falta es un selector para el enlace.

En JavaScript, a la hora de invocar un elemento de HTML, debes almacenarlo en una variable, sólo el ID no es suficiente. En este caso, usaremos el método de selección `getElementByID`, que depende de `document` y lo almacenamos en una variable.

```js
const enlace = document.getElementById('enlace');
```

Con esto, ya podrías referenciarlo en el resto de tu código.

Quedando así.

```js
const enlace = document.getElementById('enlace'); // Seleccionamos el enlace mediante su identificador

const time = new Date();
const hora = time.getHours();
 
if(hora >= 20 && hora < 8) {
  enlace.href="#"; // Modificamos su atributo href
}

// Solo para propósitos de demo, consoleamos el resultado

console.log(`Son las ${hora} horas. El enlace se ha ${hora >= 20 && hora < 8 ? 'mantenido' : 'eliminado'}`);
```

```html
<a href="http://es.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" id="enlace">El enlace</a>
```

Comment: Demás está decir muchas gracias! pero a pesar de que aquí funciona a la perfección, no me funciona ami, no se si tiene que ver alguna otra cuestión o configuración de la página. además te quiero contar que había llegados a resultados positivos solamente agregando el evento onload en la etiqueta body y cargandolo como función pero no se porque funciono un para de veces y no lo hizo más creo que la custión pasa que me funciona con el numero de la hora menos primero y despues la hora mayor

Comment: Es posible que estés cargando el JS ANTES que el html? Si es asi, quizá encuentre problemas a la hora de enconrar el elemento. Prueba a poner el atributo `defer` al importar el script, tipo `<script type="text/javascript" src="horarios.js" defer></script>`.
Esto hará que tu JS se ejecute DESPUES de que el contenido de la página haya sido cargado.

Comment: Gracias Fernando allí funcionó perfecto!

Comment: Me alegro de que funcionara correctamente :)
Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, es buena práctica aceptar la respuesta. Más info en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Agregando el evento onload en la etiqueta body y cargandolo como función pero no se porque funciono un para de veces y no lo hizo más creo que la custión pasa que me funciona con el numero de la hora menos primero y despues la hora mayor.

Script:

```
 function deshabilitar(){

      fecha = new Date(); 
      hora = fecha.getHours();
        dia=fecha.getDay();
      if(hora >=20 && hora <8 ){
         alert('Atenderemos amablemente tu consulta De 8.00 a 20.00 Hs');
          enlace.href="#";
          enlace2.href="#";
      }

      if(dia ==7,0 ){
        alert('Atenderemos amablemente tu consulta lunes a viernes');
          enlace.href="#";
          enlace2.href="#";

      }



    }
```

HTML:

```
<script src="horarios.js"></script>
<body onLoad="deshabilitar()">
```